# RPM spec %post doesn't execute in rpmbuild

Tags: rpm, rhel, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Given the minimal RPM spec file, that should only execute a `%post` stanza:

```
$ cat ~/RPMBUILD/SPECS/test.spec
Name:           None
Version:        1.0
Release:        1
Summary:        Bla
License:        Proprietary

%description
Bla

%prep

%build

%install

%clean

%post
echo ">>> Inside post <<<"

%files
```

*However,* the echo from the `%post` is **not** executed:

```
$ rpmbuild -v -bb  ~/RPMBUILD/SPECS/test.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/tmp/rpm-tmp.IvhCZs
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/tmp/rpm-tmp.yCLpOK
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/tmp/rpm-tmp.uEbSD2
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILD
+ '[' /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILDROOT/None-1.0-1.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILDROOT/None-1.0-1.x86_64
++ dirname /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILDROOT/None-1.0-1.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILDROOT/None-1.0-1.x86_64
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
Processing files: None-1.0-1.x86_64
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILDROOT/None-1.0-1.x86_64
Wrote: /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/RPMS/x86_64/None-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/tmp/rpm-tmp.wLCv3C
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/ronbarak/RPMBUILD/BUILD
+ exit 0
```

**What should I change so that the `%post` will execute?**

Comment: You are asking too fast. See my answer in you previous question http://stackoverflow.com/a/34634718/3489429

Answer (score 5):

`%post` is an install-time script section, so it will execute only when trying to install the generated rpm.

From the [documentation](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html):

> The %post script executes after the package has been installed. One of
> the most popular reasons a %post script is needed is to run ldconfig
> to update the list of available shared libraries after a new one has
> been installed. Of course, other functions can be performed in a %post
> script. For example, packages that install shells use the %post script
> to add the shell name to /etc/shells.

If you want to execute additional stuff at build time, you need to rely on the `%build` or `%install` sections.

Answer (score 2):

The `%post` section runs when you install an RPM, not during `rpmbuild`.

Further reading:

- [Scripts: RPM's Workhorse](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html)
- [How to create an RPM package](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-rpm-packages/index.html)