# rpmbuild | specfile | %post | to execute a command or script as part of rpm install

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

How to execute some commands or scripts immediately after rpm installed and has to be run as part **rpm install** command.

I wrote a spec file to take back up of some files within directory and tar them. 
When I install **rpm tar** would be copied on file system how ever I had to **untar** the ball manually to desired location.

[RPM spec %post doesn't execute in rpmbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633287/rpm-spec-post-doesnt-execute-in-rpmbuild)

The above lost helped me understand we can include %post steps in spec file itself which would do that job and commands get execute as part of rpm install command itself.

The %post section runs when you install an RPM
Note that echo command included for test purpose are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

For more information on %post in spec file please refer http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html#S2-RPM-INSIDE-BUILD-TIME-SCRIPTS